# Is it possible to autosave as docx and pdf at the same time?

Tags: microsoft-word

In `MS Word Mac`, is there a native way to save the document I am currently working on as `.docx` and a `.pdf` file with one click?

I need the document to be in both formats.

*behavior now:* first I save it as `.docx` by clicking <kbd>cmd + s</kbd>, then go to save as > pick `.pdf` from the dropdown > click export

*expected:* <kbd>cmd + s</kbd> results in 2 files, one `.pdf` and one `.docx` with current changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible. This looks like the kind of feature that you could find by Googling about it if it existed. And by default, Word will save the document in the current format (so if you're editing a .doc document, it'll save it in .doc when you hit Ctrl + S, or CMD + S in your case).